# New PayPal Sandbox Returns 400 Bad Request for IPN Verification

Tags: php, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Call it bad timing, but I had literally just gotten this working last night, right before PayPal rolled out its new developer interface.  I'm using PHP / cURL, and literally copied this code from x.com:
https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623

At 10pm last night, it started returning 400 codes with an empty response body.  Here are the response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 08 Mar 2013 16:43:16 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: c9MWDuvPtT9GIMyPc3jwol1VSlO=%7cC8szeIKENkwUqfOEYTjk-zp16RPNDC2MvLBQq9QALLYk8LcDM9kDEELRUPR_lxii1ujHBm%7cAo_aiVmV13ssvg_VFFqLkSkrVuIkUVx3O9nb09-nmQbg21hzsBAPIAIUIW8XFO_wn3c6T0%7c; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Mon, 06-Mar-2023 16:43:16 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.109.11.1362760996493186; path=/; expires=Sun, 01-Mar-43 16:43:16 GMT
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

I'm using the [IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator) to test.  Never get a "VERIFIED" or an "INVALID" response.  Only a blank response body.  Is anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently everyone is experiencing this error in the sandbox environment when we upgraded the developer accounts. We're currently working to resolve this issue however I'll be sure to update through this post you once it's resolved.

This is a completely new environment so please let me know if you are experiencing any other issues so we can correct them as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm assuming you're from PayPal, you should probably note so.

Comment: I've tested this out and Sandbox and received confirmation that this has been resolved as of Monday night. Let me know if you are continuing to receive issues and I'll take a look into this further.

Comment: I'm having the problem with the production paypal. I use WHMCS paypal module, and I receive 400 bad gateway, I tried to simulate the requests by doing following:

admin@MacbookPro:~$ curl -H "Host: 66.211.170.66" -I https://mysite.com/modules/gateways/callback/paypal.php
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 17 May 2013 18:02:39 GMT
Server: Apache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1